# Pygame dialog box: using transparent surface and gradual typing simulaneously

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make a text box for character dialog with the box transparent, and the text characters to show up one at a time. I can do one or the other separately, but when I try to combine them it doesn't make the transparency until after the typing is finished. The text is also transparent, which I don't want it to be.

My code from the game is a complex mess so I've written this code for the question. Though I've tried many variations of this without success, like per-pixel alpha, rendering the text to the main window, rendering the texbox surface alone first, and tying the gradual typing to the mainloop rather than it's own loop.

This is the code:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

textbox_surf = pygame.Surface((700,200))
textbox_surf.set_alpha(100)
textbox_rect = textbox_surf.get_rect(topleft=(150,200))
border_rect = textbox_surf.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))

FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Georgia', 24, 0)
s = "This is just an example text to use with gradual typing."
show_textbox = False
typing = False

test_text = FONT.render(s, 1, 'White')
text_rect = test_text.get_rect(topleft=(20, 90))

def gradual_typing(txt):
    global typing
    rendering = ''

    WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    for char in txt:
        pygame.time.delay(35)
        pygame.event.clear()

        rendering = rendering + char
        rendered_text = FONT.render(rendering, 1, 'White')
        text_rect = rendered_text.get_rect(topleft=(20, 90))

        pygame.draw.rect(textbox_surf, "Black", border_rect, 6)
        textbox_surf.blit(rendered_text, text_rect)
        WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)

        pygame.display.update()

    typing = False


while True:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                show_textbox = True
                typing = True

    WIN.fill('Grey')

    if show_textbox:
        textbox_surf.fill('Blue')

        if typing:
            gradual_typing(s)

        textbox_surf.blit(test_text, text_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(textbox_surf, "Black", border_rect, 4)
        WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Extra question: I notice while the text is writing by character, it seems bolder than once it finishes. It doesn't do this in my main program, does anyone know why it's doing it here? It's easier to notice if you take out the set_alpha line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textbox_surf.set_alpha(100)` makes the entire *Surface* and its entire content transparent. When you don't clear the background (fill gray), you are continuously stacking transparent surfaces. As a result, the rectangle appears opaque and the text has a slight fading effect from older text to newer text.

Create a transparent *Surface*, with the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag

```py
textbox_surf = pygame.Surface((700,200), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

Clear the display in every frame and fill `textbox_surf` with a transparent color:

```py
def gradual_typing(txt):
    # [...]

        WIN.fill('Grey')
        textbox_surf.fill((0, 0, 255, 100))
        pygame.draw.rect(textbox_surf, "Black", border_rect, 6)
        textbox_surf.blit(rendered_text, text_rect)
        WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)

        # [...]
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

textbox_surf = pygame.Surface((700,200), pygame.SRCALPHA)
textbox_rect = textbox_surf.get_rect(topleft=(150,200))
border_rect = textbox_surf.get_rect(topleft=(0, 0))

FONT = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24, 0)
s = "This is just an example text to use with gradual typing."
show_textbox = False
typing = False

test_text = FONT.render(s, 1, 'White')
text_rect = test_text.get_rect(topleft=(20, 90))

def gradual_typing(txt):
    global typing
    rendering = ''

    WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    for char in txt:
        pygame.time.delay(35)
        pygame.event.clear()

        rendering = rendering + char
        rendered_text = FONT.render(rendering, 1, 'White')
        text_rect = rendered_text.get_rect(topleft=(20, 90))

        WIN.fill('Grey')
        textbox_surf.fill((0, 0, 255, 100))
        pygame.draw.rect(textbox_surf, "Black", border_rect, 6)
        textbox_surf.blit(rendered_text, text_rect)
        WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)

        pygame.display.update()

    typing = False


while True:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                show_textbox = True
                typing = True

    WIN.fill('Grey')

    if show_textbox:

        if typing:
            gradual_typing(s)

    WIN.blit(textbox_surf, textbox_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```